# Twitterizer.TwitterUser.IsFollowing returns null

Tags: asp.net, twitter, twitterizer

I am using Twitterizer to integrate Twitter into my ASP.NET app. After authenticating the user I am using following code to see if the authenticated user is following a specific user:

```
Twitterizer.TwitterUser followed = new Twitterizer.TwitterUser();
followed.ScreenName = tw_current_like;
bool? Following = followed.IsFollowing;
```

However `Following.HasValue` is always false. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I stated on the forums. Instantiating `TwitterUser` will not fetch any data from Twitter.

Also, the Twitter API is spotty in how/when it supplies the following indicator. You can use `TwitterFriendship.Show(OAuthTokens, decimal/string)` to query details about the relationship between the authenticated user and another user.